# Passing multiple provider aliases to a module in terraform 0.12.13

Tags: terraform

I'm building code that needs to talk to two different AWS accounts, which the documentation says should work.  This worked under 0.11.14

In the main, in my providers.tf file I have:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias = "ca-central-1"
  region = "ca-central-1"
  profile = var.aws_profile
}

provider "aws" {
   alias = "other-ca-central-1"
   region = "ca-central-1"
   profile = var.aws_other_profile
}
```

(Those variables are set the correct profiles in my credentials file.)

In the root, in the code that calls the module,

```
module "obfuscated" {
  source = "./modules/obfuscated"
  providers = {
    aws.main = "aws.ca-central-1"
    aws.other = "aws.other-ca-central-1"
  }
  #other stuff
}
```

In ./modules/obfuscated/main.tf I have

```
provider "aws" {
  alias = "main"
}
provider "aws" {
  alias = "other"
}
```

Which the docs say is a placeholder, which can only be empty or have an alias.  Without it, it complains the provider doesn't exist.
But with it, it complains I didn't specify the region, which conflicts with the docs.

Surely the documentation couldn't be wrong, no, that couldn't be possible..  Help me obi-wan-overflow..

Comment: Is that `"aws-other-ca-central-1"` an accurate copy of what you tried, or was that just an editorial error while presenting your comment? The correct syntax for that would be `aws.other-ca-central-1` (with a period rather than a dash), and in Terraform 0.12 you don't need to quote those references although Terraform 0.12 will accept it if you do, for compatibility with 0.11.

Comment: Transcription typo.

Comment: They probably made a breaking change without documenting it. The Terraform docs have inaccuracies in places, most notably in the `terraform taint` section for a long time.

Answer (score 13):

The solution provided by [@NeoVance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3616833/neovance) is almost solving it.  Indeed, the `required_providers` block is required in the module, but it requires the so called `configuration_aliases`, additionally.

```
terraform {
    required_providers {
        aws = {
            source  = "hashicorp/aws"
            version = ">= 2.7.0"
            configuration_aliases = [ aws.main, aws.other ]
        }
    }
}
```

Here your can find the related documentation about [Passing Providers Explicitely](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/providers#passing-providers-explicitly).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how I am handling the issue

```
#af-south-1
data aws_vpcs af-south-1 {
    provider = aws.af-south-1
}

module af-south-1 {
    source = "./modules/flow_log"
    providers = {
        aws = aws.af-south-1
    }
    iam_role_arn = aws_iam_role.vpc_flow_log.arn
    log_destination = aws_s3_bucket.vpc_flow_log.arn
    log_destination_type = "s3"
    traffic_type = "REJECT"
    aws_vpc_ids = data.aws_vpcs.af-south-1.ids
    depends_on = [ aws_s3_bucket.vpc_flow_log ]
}

#ap-east-1
data aws_vpcs ap-east-1 {
    provider = aws.ap-east-1
}

module ap-east-1 {
    source = "./modules/flow_log"
    providers = {
        aws = aws.ap-east-1
    }
    iam_role_arn = aws_iam_role.vpc_flow_log.arn
    log_destination = aws_s3_bucket.vpc_flow_log.arn
    log_destination_type = "s3"
    traffic_type = "REJECT"
    depends_on = [ aws_s3_bucket.vpc_flow_log ]
    aws_vpc_ids = data.aws_vpcs.ap-east-1.ids
}

#ap-northeast-1
data aws_vpcs ap-northeast-1 {
    provider = aws.ap-northeast-1
}
....
```

In this example I am creating a datasource `aws_vpcs` for each provider region. Then I pass the list of ids for each region into the module. At this time you must specify the provider for the module to use unless you are using the default provider.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem may be that you are attempting to pass the providers values as strings rather than references to the actual provider. `"aws.<alias>"` vs `aws.<alias>`

I could be wrong, but I think you will need to include `required_providers` in your module `terraform` block.

```
terraform {
    required_providers {
        aws = {
            source  = "hashicorp/aws"
            version = ">= 2.7.0"
        }
    }
}
```

Then you may use an empty `provider` or one with `alias` to declare the provider as a required item to be passed in the modules `providers` configuration.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same kind of issue but for assuming a role. So in my case, I provide the role arn to use. In the module directory, for example ***my_module***, I have a tf file with the provider. Inside the block provider, I have this:

```
variable "role_arn" {}

provider "aws" {
  alias   = "first"
  region  = "eu-west-1"
  version = "2.24.0"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "${var.role_arn}"
  }
}
```

In a tf file within my_module directory, using the provider for creating an EC2 instance for example, I have this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "my_instance" {
  [...]
  provider = "aws.first"
}
```

And in the root directory of my project, I have this:

```
module "using_my_module" {
  source = "modules/my_module"

  role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/role_to_assume"
}
```

I admit it is a technical workaround so it might look ugly but it worked for me!

I hope it would help you!